# super class doesn't work with subclass, a init fun is defined but doesn't act accordantly

Tags: python, class, superclass

I am trying to create a class within a class, and when running my program the object doesn't get any of the attributes.
it is created as a default object without the defaults that I set

I was expecting the object to take the values that I gave him and to be made as coded

Code:
from turtle import Turtle
import random

class Food(Turtle):

```
def __int__(self):
    super().__init__()
    self.shape("circle")
    self.penup()
    self.shapesize(stretch_len=0.5, stretch_wid=0.5)
    self.color("blue")
    self.speed(0)
    self.goto(random.randint(-250, 250), random.randint(-250, 250))
```

and while running a get a default turtle object

Comment: Please show the code you're having trouble with

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This is a common typo, for which I have written a canonical Q&A - please see the link.

Comment: maybe problem in `__int__` instead of `__init__`